# Is there a function for computing the N-dimensional convex hull in Julia?

Tags: julia, convex-hull, convex, n-dimensional

Does such a function exist yet? If so, where can I find it?

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of Matlab's convhulln() function. It takes as its input a data set (with N dimensions) and returns the data points that belong to the convex hull of that data space.

Answer (score 4):

See [CHull.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/CHull.jl), which has a wrapper to `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` (N-dimensional)

```
using CHull

p = rand(10,2)
ch = chull(p)
ch.points         # original points
ch.vertices       # indices to line segments forming the convex hull
show(ch)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! you saved me a lot of time